# How to retrieve data from Firebase using ArrayList?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase using ArrayList.
I read a lot of things, but I can't figure out.

[image]

"1111" is userID.
I want to get lists of memo according to userID.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  Query q1 = databaseReference11.child("Memo").child(userId);
         q1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                         for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                          Mome mome = data.getValue(Mome.class);
                            ArrayList.add(mome);
                       } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
Query q1 = databaseReference11.child("Memo").child(userId).child(pushedId);
q1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     String memo = dataSnapshot.child("memo").getValue(String.class);
     arrayList.add(memo);
}
```

In which `pushedId` is the unique id generated by the `push()` methos. Hope it helps.